# Spring4 MVC Controller Pageable not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want Spring auto build Pageable object in controller . So I define :

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
public String list(Model model , Pageable pageable) {
  logger.info("pageable = {}" , pageable);
  // ... skipped
}
```

And I define `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` in the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` :

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setMaxPageSize(10);
    resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
    argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
  }
}
```

I override page size to 10 (default is 20) , and set to 1-based paging. When running the page . I see the log :

```
Controller - pageable = Page request [number: 0, size 10, sort: null]
```

If I add parameter '`?page=1&size=1`' to the URL , it still prints :

```
Controller - pageable = Page request [number: 0, size 10, sort: null]
```

If I change parameter to `?sort=id` , it logs :

```
Controller - pageable = Page request [number: 0, size 10, sort: id: ASC]
```

It seems my default size (10) is working , and `sort` parameter is correctly passed to Pageable . But why parameter page and size not working here ?

In `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` source code , it designates

```
private static final String DEFAULT_PAGE_PARAMETER = "page";
private static final String DEFAULT_SIZE_PARAMETER = "size";
```

But I don't know why it still not works. Did I miss anything ?

Environments:

```
spring-boot 1.3.1.RELEASE
spring-webmvc 4.2.3.RELEASE
```

========= Updated =========

Thanks @TimeTravel's answer.

It seems there's no way to define an `1-based` & `size` is truly 10 (not minus one = 9) `Pageable` object here .

The correct solution is still pending... (except manually creation)

========= Updated Again =========

It seems it is the bug of `spring-data-jpa:1.9.0.RELEASE` . After upgrading to `spring-data-jpa:1.9.2.RELEASE` , it works now.

See [DATACMNS-761](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-761) for detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to call the super class addArgumentResolvers method with your argumentResolvers as the argument.

```
 super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
```

Check the code below.

```
@Override
  public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setMaxPageSize(10);
    resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
    argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
    super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
  }
```

Since you did set     [`resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html#setOneIndexedParameters-boolean-), your page `number` will start with 0. So if you set the `page=1` in the URL, the pageable object will have `number=0`. If you set it to false or remove that statement, then the `size=1` in URL will have `number=1` in `pageable` object.

From the documentation - 
[protected boolean isOneIndexedParameters()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html#setOneIndexedParameters-boolean-)

> Indicates whether to expose and assume 1-based page number indexes in
>   the request parameters. Defaults to false, meaning a page number of 0
>   in the request equals the first page. If this is set to true, a page
>   number of 1 in the request will be considered the first page.

With the above two changes in place -

`page=1&sort=id&size=1` will return   `[number: 1, size 1, sort: id: ASC]`

Comment: Thanks it works. BTW , I find `resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);` also affects the size , which is very strange. For example , if `&size=10` , it logs 'size 9' .  If I didn't set it true , size is correctly passed.

Comment: Yes..your are correct about `resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);` This is because it assumes that the page number starts with `0`, the size will be decremented by 1.

Comment: I think size shouldn't be affected by 1-based or 0-based paging, which is very counter intuitive .

Comment: BTW , There seems no way to define an `1-based` & `size` is truly 10 (not minus one = 9) Pageable object here ?